# Laravel 4 - object retrieval from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel and have a categories table created in my MySql database which has fields for using tree traversal navigation:

```
id | parent_id | name  | lft | rgt | depth 
 1 |      NULL | test1 | 1   | 2   |     0
 2 |      NULL | test2 | 3   | 4   |     0
 3 |         1 | test3 | 5   | 6   |     1
```

I want to retrieve the objects that have `depth = 0` (`test1` and `test2`).

I have this function in my controller:

```
public function getIndex() {
  $categories = array();

  foreach(Category::all() as $category)
  {
      $categories[$category->depth = '0'] = $category->name;
  }

  return View::make('categories.index')
      ->with('categorieslist', $categories);
}
```

But it always returns the last item (`test2`). It needs to return all the objects with `depth = 0`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are saving (and overwriting) your data on position `$category->depth = '0'` of your array $categories

Not familiar with Laravel, but this should do the trick:

```
public function getIndex() {
    $categories = array();

    foreach(Category::all() as $category) {
        //If depth equals zero
        if ($category->depth == 0) {
            //append $category->name to $categories
            $categories[] = $category->name;
        }
    }

    return View::make('categories.index')->with('categorieslist', $categories);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get categories by using the below code:

```
$categories = Category::where('depth', '=', 0)->select('name')->get()->toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your foreach loop. You are iterating through all the categories actually and placing them at the 0th position. I guess, this should do the trick:

```
public function getIndex() {
     $categories = array();
    $all_parent_categories = Category::where('depth','=','0')->get();
    $i=0;
     foreach(Category::all() as $category)
      {
          $categories[$i] = $category->name;
          $i++;
      }
      return View::make('categories.index')->with('categorieslist', $categories);
    }
```